# How to Save/Load data from TableView in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, io, tableview

I have created a TableView that allows the user to enter information into the table. The issue I am having is that I need to save the information the user provided, and reload the same table, with the same information the next time the program is ran.  I've been stuck for some time on this, if anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it.  BELOW is my ObservableList and the methods I tried.  I will include a screen capture of what the table looks like.  I called the methods from button pushes the user would make.

```
//get Trail info
public static ObservableList<Stats> getTrailInfo(){
    ObservableList<Stats>  trailInfo = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); 
    trailInfo.add(new Stats(trailList, timesHiked, daysHiked, hoursHiked, minutesHiked, milesHiked));

    return trailInfo;
}


//I ATTEMPTED TO SAVE AND READ IT BACK USING THESE METHODS, BUT I DID NOT HAVE ANY LUCK
private static void write(ObservableList<Stats> stats) {
    try {

        // write object to file
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("TrailName.txt");           
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
        oos.writeObject(new ArrayList<Stats>(stats));
        oos.close();


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

static ObservableList<Stats> pull() {
    try {
        InputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream("TrailName.txt");           
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(inputstream);
        List<Stats> list = (List<Stats>) ois.readObject() ;

        return FXCollections.observableList(list);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return FXCollections.emptyObservableList();
}
[TableView ScreenShot][1]


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0nyg.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Does Stats implement java.io.Serializable?  From the API docs from ObjectOutputStream:

> Only objects that support the java.io.Serializable interface can be written to streams.

From the docs on Serializable:

> Serializability of a class is enabled by the class implementing the java.io.Serializable interface. Classes that do not implement this interface will not have any of their state serialized or deserialized.

Comment: I am not sure if it should be serializable TBH.  I tried several thing and they did not work, that was the last thing that I tried from another example.  For whatever reason I cannot find any examples online on how to save the Tableview and its data and then reload it.